# Nearby API MessageListener doesn't trigger callbacks

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to send Beacon Messages from my Eddystone Beacon (micro:bit) to my Android application using [Nearby API](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/get-beacon-messages). I literally copied all their code from documentation but `onLost` and `onFound` callbacks are never triggered. The application starts listening and nothing happens then. I know that the beacon is just fine because I can receive messages on `Bluetooth Beacon Interactor` on my PC.
This is my code:

```
 mMessageListener = new MessageListener() {
     @Override
     public void onFound(Message message) {
         Log.d("HomepageActivity", "Found message: " + new String(message.getContent()));
         mMessageContent.setText(message.getContent().toString());
     }

     @Override
     public void onLost(Message message) {
         Log.d("HomepageActivity", "Lost sight of message: " + new String(message.getContent()));
     }
 };


@OnClick(R.id.mSubscribe)
public void subscribe() {
    Log.i("HomepageActivity", "Subscribing.");
    SubscribeOptions options = new SubscribeOptions.Builder()
            .setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY)
            .build();
    Nearby.getMessagesClient(this).subscribe(mMessageListener, options);
}`
```

This is the whole error message I get in LOGCAT: https://pastebin.com/1UwJ37TV

Answer (score 0):

the `SubscribeOptions.Builder` has one method `.setCallback()` ...

which permit to assign a [SubscribeCallback](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/messages/SubscribeCallback) (which you might be missing).

that callback only has one method `onExpired()`. ignoring the expiry most likely caused the crash.

Comment: Hmm, I still don't understand. So I have to add methods onFound() and onLost() in SubscribeCallback or what? Give me more details please.

Comment: @doksara you need both, the listener and the callback. `subscribe()` may never be called ...because the logcat does not read `Subscribing` anywhere. this means the click event already fails. I'd replace `@OnClick(R.id.mSubscribe)` with something that actually binds the click event. the stack-trace also hints for the `onExpired()` callback being ignored.

Comment: Actually, the event suceeds..there is a message in LogCat: 
2018-11-24 22:42:26.046 6205-6205/hr.foi.air.microsensor I/HomepageActivity: Subscribing.
But after that, simply nothing happens. I tried moving them under same function but it ain't helping.

Comment: @doksara it doesn't ...when I search the page for `Subscribing` it reads `0/0`. this means that `Log.i("HomepageActivity", "Subscribing.");` is never being called. and if there are indeed attempts to subscribe, the connection might not be in the proper state to do so - or it may subscribe somewhere else in code and then subscribe twice. search GitHub for `Nordic Semiconductor`, for some proven to be working `BLE` examples.